# Bash output from expect script to two different files

Tags: bash, tee

I am trying to output to two different files using `tee`. My first file will basically be `tail -f /myfile` and my second output will be a subset of the first file. I have looked online that they were saying we can use `|

```
tee >(proc1) >(proc2)
```

I have tried the above but both my files are blank.

Here is what i have so far:

myscript.sh

```
ssh root@server 'tail -f /my/dir/text.log' | tee >(/mydir/my.log) >(grep 'string' /mydir/my.log > /mydir/mysecond.log)
```

myexpect.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set pass password

spawn /my/dir/myexpect.sh
expect {
    "key fingerprint" {send "yes/r"; exp_contiue}
    "assword: " {send "$pass\r"}
}
interact
```

Comment: You can just tell SSH to always accept the remote key with command-line options -- you don't need `expect` for that. Opens you up to man-in-the-middle attacks, but you get those when always accepting the remote key without validating its correctness in any account. And to send a password -- it's similarly awful for security, but see `sshpass`.

Comment: `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, specifically, indicates that you don't care about the presented host key. It is, of course, a Very Bad Idea, but so is having `expect` automatically accept host keys, and so is having users be in the habit of typing `yes` without understanding what they're doing. (For folks who actually give a damn about security, it's worth thinking about publishing host keys via DNSSEC or signing them with a SSH CA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, there are some problems in the usage of `tee`,

1. `tee >(/mydir/my.log)`: can be substitute with `tee /mydir/my.log`, since `tee` would write to stdout and files, i.e. /mydir/my.log
2. `grep 'string' /mydir/my.log > /mydir/mysecond.log`: as I mentioned, `tee` would also write to stdout, so no need to `grep` the string from file, you can grep from stdout directly. Use pipeline to do it.

So the whole command shall be modified as followed,

```
ssh root@server 'tail -f /my/dir/text.log | tee /mydir/my.log | grep --line-buffered "string" > /mydir/mysecond.log'
```

**Edit:**

For your further question

- The command would hang because of `tail -f` was still waiting for output the growing file. If you don't want the command hanged, try to remove -f for `tail`.
- Depends on the option -f existed for `tail`, you shall use two different way to allow the `grep` write file.

  - For `tail` case: `grep` can successfully write file
  - For `tail -f` case: `--line-buffered` for `grep` would use line buffering on output

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after changing it to your suggested code when I run my expect script it hangs in the prompt password `root@server's password:` and doesn't log in.

Comment: but mysecond.log has no content in there. only the first one does.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour, see my modification for your further question

Comment: Okay, thank you for the additional explanation! So for my case, since I need to monitor the continuous output I will need to use the -f option with the `--line-buffered`, and it will always hang because it needs to wait for the output correct? I used the `--line-buffered` and now I do see both logs get updated successfully, it just hangs on the login prompt.

Comment: Yes, you can try `tail -f ${your_test_file}` on your local side, it would hang as well